# the best or speedest way to understand uncommented and complex project

Tags: project-management, project, projects-and-solutions, solution

I have complex project without comments. The project is programed in Java but have more than one main class, use several .txt files like a template and use several .bat files. I don't know where to start and how to start discovering the project, because I need to make some changes in that project.

Comment: I believe this situation is called "Hell."

Comment: Speak to the client. Only they probably know what they wanted.

Comment: Number one recommendation of mine is, Be upfront with the client, tell them it will take time to unravel, and ask for more time than you think you'll need.

Comment: I know what client want but I don't know where to implement inside the project.

Answer (score 6):

As with others I say this is a slow process.

However having done this in the past many times, this is my methodology:

1. Identify as many requirements that the code fulfils. This may give you the some reasons as to why certain things are the way they are when you look deeper. A common way of finding these is look for any tests that be available. The automated ones are best, but usually they're as missing as the comments.
2. Find the entry points to the code. These will give you places where you can poke the code to see how different inputs affect the flow. Common entry points are Code Loading 'Main' type functions, service interfaces, web page post backs etc..
3. Diagram the code. Look for tools that can build black/white box pictures of the code. For me this invaluable. I have on occasion printed out large listings and attacked then with markers and rulers. You're aim to create your own flow chart (mental or other wise) of the code flow.
4. Using the above (iteratively) build a set of outputs to the code that you think should occur, and add to these the outputs you may already know about such as logs, data files, database writes etc..
5. Finally if you have time, create some manual tests though preferably in automated test harnesses to verify the above. This where I start to involve the debugger to see detail in the code.

This methodology usually gives me confidence to make changes.

*Note this is iterative process and can be done with portions of the code or overall as you see fit. I usually favour a top down approach to start with and then as I gain some insight I drill down till details become overwhelming and then I repeat. However this is just because my mind works in this way - you may be different. Good luck.*

Comment: 6. Start to add the missing documentations

Answer (score 3):

Find the main Main class. The starting point.
Start drawing a picture of the classes and the objects they own and the external entities they reference.
Follow all the branches until you can find a logical ending.

I've used UML reverse engineering tools in the past and while a visual picture is good, stepping through the code has always been the hardest and yet best methodology for me.

And, as you step through each piece you can add in your own comments..

Comment: and the easiest way to find this is with the .bat files - see what classes are called from the command line, that's your entry point.

Answer (score 3):

I usually start with doxygen, turning on every extracting option (especially EXTRACT_ALL and EXTRACT_PRIVATE), and enable the SOURCE_BROWSER, HAVE_DOT, CALL_GRAPH and CALLER_GRAPH options (you also need to have dot installed). This gives good view of the software. For every function the calls are displayed and linked in a graph, also the sources are linked from there.

While doxygen is intended for C and C++, it also works with Java sources (set the OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA option).

Answer (score 2):

I would try to find the first entry point in the code closest to where you suspect you'll need to start making your changes, **set a breakpoint, and start debugging**. **Check out the contents of local variables** and work your way deeper as you get to become familiar with whats going on. Then, when you have a basic understanding of the area of code you're going to be working with, **start fiddling with some small changes**. Test your understanding of it. **Try diagramming what you see happening**. If you can do that confidently, you'll be able to decide if you need to go back and continue learning more about the code, or if you know enough to get done what you need to get done.

Answer (score 2):

Auch. I'm afraid there is no speedy way to do this. Comment out a line (or two) -> test -> see what breaks. You could also put break statements here and there and run the debugger. That should give you some indication how you got there (ie. what the hierarchy between the classes is).

Hopefully the original developers used some patterns that you can recognize and make notes. Make lots of notes of everything. Start by trying to understand the high level structure and work down from there.

Be prepared to spend endless hours not understanding what the thing is doing.

Speak to the client and try to understand what the project is for, and what are all the things that it does. Someone somewhere had to put in some requirements for the stuff that's in there, if only in an email.

Answer (score 0):

A start is to use an automated uml modeling tool (if you use eclipse you can use a plug-gin), and start creating UML diagrams of the various classes to see how they are related in a high level and visualize the code. This has helped many times

Comment: If this plug-in will recognize the .bat and the .txt files.

Comment: @GoGoo:I am refering to the java classes. Try this http://www.soyatec.com/main.php it has free version. You create visual uml diagrams of the java code and start visualizing the project. Once you understand the code in high level it will be easier to find which part of code does what, and where to dive in.

Answer (score 0):

If there are log files being generated, have a look at it to understand the flow from the starting point (main class). Otherwise, put debug statements to understand the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, that sounds like a pretty bad spot to be in.

I would say that the best way is to just walk through the program line for line. Try to grasp the big picture in the code, and write alot of notes, both on paper and in comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, a good approach would be to generate documentation using javadoc or doxygen's class diagram feature, then as you run the code traverse through the class diagrams generated using doxygen and see who calls what. This works wonderfully for me everytime i am working on such a project.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree to most of the answers posted.

I can add to use a development tool that reverse engineering the code and create a class diagram, to have an overall picture of what is involved.

Then you need patience. But you will be a stronger and smarter developer when you'll get through...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of the best and first things to do is to try to build and run the code. It might sound a bit simplistic but the problem when you take over undocumented code is that you can't even build it and run it. When have no clue were to start.